# Has OptaPlanner wrong illustration for ChangeMove on a chained planning entity?

Tags: java, optaplanner

well I looked at this illustration in [docs](https://docs.optaplanner.org/7.19.0.Final/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#changeMoveSelector):

[image]

in docs it says:

> For one planning variable, the ChangeMove selects one planning entity and one planning value and assigns the entity’s variable to that value.

but if we would do exactly what it says, we would end up in an invalid state, where both `Amts.` and `Berlin` are pointing to `Brus.` as their parent?

The illustration is actually showing a `SubChainChangeMove` with length = 1. So is OptaPlanner automatically replace `ChangeMove` by a `SubChainChangeMove` when it encounters chained variables or do I understand it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OptaPlanner handles ChangeMove's **on chained variables** differently: it does chain correction to avoid getting into an invalid state. See ChainedChangeMove that extends ChangeMove.

Comment: thx for the explanation. Maybe you should add this info to the docs. I was somehow confused as I read the docs

Comment: https://docs.optaplanner.org/7.19.0.Final/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#changeMoveSelector